# Cannot uninstall new update KB:4489881 (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, uninstallation

Hi guys im having **troubles uninstalling newest Windows Update KB:4489881**, which completely slowed my PC.

- I tried using Uninstall Update through Control Panel, did not work,
  tried `/uninstall /kb:xxx` did not work either.
- I tried `dism`, but `dism /online /get-packages /format:table >
  patches.txt` does not list kb im looking for, while listing all
  others, so i cannot perform deleting package, with no specified name.

What's funnier, I was able to normally delete it previously using Control Panel, then I turned off all updates to make sure it doesn't appear again, but it got updated again without me knowing the day after, since then i cannot uninstall it like i did previously.

Answer (score 0):

Restart in safe mode. Go to control panel, windows updates, and click on installed updates. You should see there an entry about KB4489881. Right click on it and select to uninstall. Reboot the computer.